# Loading core data into array, then populating table view, reordering array's objects doesnt persist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsmutablearray

First let me tell you what im trying to do. Load data into array(from core data entity), populate table view, 
if user wants, reorder cells and update the array.

Thats it.

I have found my problem, i just dont know how to fix it:

I am loading my Entities data/attributes into an array and populating my tableview with the data
(BELOW BEHOLDS THE PROBLEM):

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
if (self.context == nil)
{
    self.context = [(RootAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
}
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"HandgunAmmo" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
[request setEntity:entity];
NSError *error;
//PROBLEM!!! the 2 lines below this. 
NSMutableArray *array = [[self.context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
[self setTableArray:array];
[self.ammoTable reloadData];
[super viewWillAppear:YES];
}
```

SO at this point the table view is loaded with data (accounting for `cellForRow` being called)

The user moves a few cells around, and i update the array as follows:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
    // fetch the object at the row being moved
NSString *r = [self.tableArray objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];

    // remove the original from the data structure
[self.tableArray removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];

    // insert the object at the target row
[self.tableArray insertObject:r atIndex:toIndexPath.row];

[self.ammoTable reloadData];

}
```

As you can see the code for reordering the array should work.

But, in the `viewWillAppear` method, I am loading the entities attributes into the array again and using it to populate the table view which is the problem. When i update the array, its not updating the order of the objects inside of the entity. Does anyone know how to update that? I would really appreciate it!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The managedObjects represented in the array have no sense of their position in the array. Therefore rearranging their place is changing their visible position but not their position in the database.

If you want to sort then you need to do some things:

1. Have your `NSFetchRequest` include an NSPredicate that sorts on a sort field
2. Have your `moveRowAtIndexPath` method not only reposition the data but also update the sort field to reflect their new position
3. Save the updated records to the database so that the next fetch will have the correct sort.

If you already have a fetchResultsController you can forgo the array and just use:

```
NSManagedObject *ammo = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:fromIndexPath];
```

To get an reference to the current object.

Comment: thank you for the help! I do just have one question if you don't mind. What exactly do you mean my a `sort field`? THanks a bunch!

Comment: Add a field to your model called 'order' and make it an integer.  You can assign each row a value when you create it.  When you reorder rows swap their order value before you save.

Comment: i do apologize. I am not trying to get you to do the work for me or anything like that, im just having a hard time understanding you. By `adding a field` it seems like you mean a `textField`? but then you say `make it an integer` which obviously isnt possible to have a textfield be an int, so what do you mean by `field` exactly? Thank you very much, and sorry again to be such a pain!

Comment: No problem.  Click your AppName.xcdatamodeld file and go to the entity your are trying to reorder.  Add an attribute to that entity called 'order' with a type of Integer 32.  Before you do all of this you'll want to create a new model version (Editor -> Add Model version) and make it the active version.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Oh gosh! haha i was just being dense. Thanks a bunch! ill try it out and hopefully it works, ill check mark the answer in just a few. Thank you again Richard! :)

Comment: hey rich im sorry to bother you again, how may i add a value to each cell ( i thought i may do this using tags?) and store it in the `order` attribute?(I dont see how i can store it in this attribute since its not a `container` type object.  I cannot wrap my head around this simple concept. Thank you!

Comment: The cells don't need to know their order, that's the datasource's responsibility.  The order value is stored in the entity and used by the NSPredicate to sort the data before it's handed out by the datasource.  Changing the order is handled by moveRowAtIndexPath.